# R: Writing a Random Sampling Procedure for Coin Flips

Tags: r

Suppose we have the following situation:

- There is a coin where if it lands head then the probability of the next flip being heads is 0.6 (and if tails then the next flip being tails is also 0.6)
- There are 100 students in a class
- Each student flips this coin a random number of times
- The last flip of student_n does not influence the first flip of student_n+1 (i.e. when the next student flips the coin, the first flip has 0.5 probability of heads or tails, but the next flip for this student depends on the previous flip)

Here is some R code to represent this problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
ids <- 1:100
student_id <- sort(sample(ids, 100000, replace = TRUE))
coin_result <- character(1000)
coin_result[1] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)

for (i in 2:length(coin_result)) {
  if (student_id[i] != student_id[i-1]) {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)
  } else if (coin_result[i-1] == "H") {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.6, 0.4))
  } else {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.4, 0.6))
  }
}

my_data <- data.frame(student_id, coin_result)
my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$student_id),]

final <- my_data %>%
    group_by(student_id) %>%
    mutate(flip_number = row_number())
The data looks something like this:

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   student_id [1]
  student_id coin_result  flip_number
       <int> <chr>              <int>
1          1 H                      1
2          1 H                      2
3          1 H                      3
4          1 H                      4
5          1 T                      5
6          1 H                      6
```

**My Problem:** In this scenario, let's say that I do not have any prior knowledge about this coin (i.e. I only have access to the data from the students) and I think its possible that the coin might have "correlated probabilities" - particularly, I think the result of the previous flip might influence the next flip. To test this hypothesis, I can perform the following analysis:

- Randomly sample with replacement students until you have the same number of students as the original data.
- For each of these students selected, randomly choose a starting point x
  and ending point y (where y>x), and select all available data between x
  and y
  for a given student.
- Then, calculate the probabilities and 95% Confidence Intervals.
- Repeat this process k
  times.

**Here is my attempt to code the above procedure:**

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

n_boot <- 1000

boot_results2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = n_boot, ncol = 4)
colnames(boot_results2) <- c("P(H|H)", "P(T|H)", "P(H|T)", "P(T|T)")

for (b in 1:n_boot) {

  print(b)
  

  boot_students <- sample(unique(final$student_id), replace = TRUE)
  

  boot_data <- data.frame(student_id = integer(0), coin_result = character(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  for (s in boot_students) {

    student_data <- final %>% filter(student_id == s)
    

    x <- sample(nrow(student_data), 1)
    y <- sample(x:nrow(student_data), 1)
    

    student_data <- student_data[x:y, ]
    

    boot_data <- rbind(boot_data, student_data)
  }
  

  p_hh <- mean(boot_data$coin_result[-1] == "H" & boot_data$coin_result[-nrow(boot_data)] == "H")
  p_th <- mean(boot_data$coin_result[-1] == "H" & boot_data$coin_result[-nrow(boot_data)] == "T")
  p_ht <- mean(boot_data$coin_result[-1] == "T" & boot_data$coin_result[-nrow(boot_data)] == "H")
  p_tt <- mean(boot_data$coin_result[-1] == "T" & boot_data$coin_result[-nrow(boot_data)] == "T")
  
  boot_results2[b, ] <- c(p_hh, p_th, p_ht, p_tt)
}
```

**My Question:** While the code seems to be running - it is taking a very long time to run. I am also not sure if I have written this correctly.

Can someone please show me how to do this correctly?

Thanks!

**Note:** Optional Code to Visualize Results:

```
library(ggplot2)

boot_results_long2 <- as.data.frame(boot_results2)
boot_results_long2$iteration <- 1:n_boot
boot_results_long2 <- boot_results_long2 %>%
  gather(key = "coin", value = "probability", -iteration)


ggplot(boot_results_long2, aes(x = iteration, y = probability, color = coin)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Iteration", y = "Probability", color = "Coin") +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("P(H|H)", "P(T|H)", "P(H|T)", "P(T|T)"))
```

Comment: a couple of thoughts: 1. I'm not totally 100% confident on the statistics, as it's not my area of expertise- if you're unsure about the statistical basis for the idea, you might want to make sure on Cross Validated

Comment: 2. the reason it runs slowly is likely that you're using for loops (and nested for loops at that). If you can move things into`map`s or `apply`s then it would probably speed things up a bit. You might get more tips on here, or on Code Review, idk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the main bottleneck is the inner loop. We can make that inner loop about 20x as fast by replacing:

```
tictoc::tic()
for (s in boot_students) {
  student_data <- final %>% filter(student_id == s)
  x <- sample(nrow(student_data), 1)
  y <- sample(x:nrow(student_data), 1)
  student_data <- student_data[x:y, ]
  boot_data <- rbind(boot_data, student_data)
}
tictoc::toc()
# around 2.5s on my machine
```

with

```
tictoc::tic()
boot_data <- final %>%
    left_join(
      final %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        summarize(n = n(), .by = student_id) %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(x = sample(1:n, 1),
               y = sample(x:n, 1))
    ) %>%
    filter(flip_number >= x, flip_number <= y)
tictoc::toc()
# around 0.1s on my machine
```

Your original loop includes a few inefficient steps:

1. create separate subset of final for each of 1000 students (we can skip this)
2. pick random start (x) and end (y) from x:n for each student. (let's do this once and be [vectorized](https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/))
3. subset the data (let's do this once instead of 1000x)
4. append to the prior students' data (we can skip this if we never separate the data by student to begin with)

It would be more efficient to do (2) for all the students at once, then (3), skipping 1+4. 4 is particularly costly, see chapter 2 ("Growing Objects") of the R Inferno: https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

I'm confident this could be accelerated much further, but perhaps this gets into the region of "fast enough for now."

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will try running this right now! Will the final results be in the same format? Is it still possible to use the ggplot code to make the same graph?

Comment: I expect so, please let me know if you notice anything awry.

Comment: @JonSpring: thank you! I will try to make a graph in ggplot2...

Answer (score 2):

If we want to sample each `student_id` without any weight, we can approach it similar to @JonSpring's brilliant answer by grouping instead of joining. For my computer, the `data.table` approach is about 3 times faster than the `dplyr` method below.

```r
my_sample = function(data) {
  x = sample(nrow(data), 1L)
  y = sample(x:nrow(data), 1L)
  return(data[x:y,])
}

## dplyr
final %>%
  group_by(student_id) %>%
  group_modify(~(my_sample(.x)))

## data.table
library(data.table)
finalDT = as.data.table(ungroup(final))
finalDT[, my_sample(.SD), student_id]
```

If we instead want to do something similar to `boot_students = sample(unique(final$student_id), replace = TRUE)` and loop through them, the `data.table` solution should be relatively performant as we can set a key up front and then loop through all of the students to filter.

```r
setkey(finalDT, student_id)
boot_students = sample(unique(final$student_id), replace = TRUE)

lapply(boot_students,
       function (student)  finalDT[student_id == student, my_sample(.SD)]) |>
  rbindlist()
```

For me, it is about 20x faster than OP and provides identical results as original inner loop. This approach could be made more performant if we dropped to `Rcpp` as there are methods to subset `data.table` in `Rcpp` now which should be more efficient. But... it's probably fast enough ;).

As an aside, we probably can do the end part more efficiently using `table` and potentially `prop.table()`.

```r
## from above
boot_data = lapply(boot_students,
       function (student)  finalDT[student_id == student, my_sample(.SD)]) %>%
  rbindlist()

## table and prop.table on separate lines so intermediate results can be seen
table(head(boot_data$coin_result, -1), tail(boot_data$coin_result, -1)) |>
  prop.table()

##              H         T
##    H 0.2820237 0.2035307
##    T 0.2035307 0.3109150
```

To graph, we could simply replace the inner loop of OP with one of the examples above. Alternatively, this could be a way to graph using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) and [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot). Instead of `geom_line()` which might not be the best for discrete data, here is `geom_boxplot()` but more thought could be put into how to visualize it.

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

## initializing data.table 
finalDT = as.data.table(ungroup(final))
setkey(finalDT, student_id)

## helper methods to subset and then transform into prop.table
my_sample = function(data) {
  x = sample(nrow(data), 1L)
  y = sample(x:nrow(data), 1L)
  return(data[x:y,])
}

create_prop_table = function (x) {
  table(head(x, -1L), tail(x, -1L)) |>
    prop.table()
}

## subset up front for small optimization
unique_students = unique(finalDT[["student_id"]])

## lapply is just a loop
lapply(seq_len(n_boot), 
       function(iteration) {
         boot_students = sample(unique_students, replace = TRUE)
         finalDT[.(boot_students), my_sample(.SD), by = .EACHI
                 ][, as.data.table(create_prop_table(coin_result))
                   ][,c("iteration", "coin") := .(iteration, paste0("P(",V1, "|", V2, ")"))]
       }) |> 
  rbindlist() |> ## combine 100 simulations into one data.table
  ggplot(aes(x = coin, y = N, color = coin)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Coin", y = "Probability", color = "Coin") +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("P(H|H)", "P(T|H)", "P(H|T)", "P(T|T)")) +
  ggtitle(paste0("Randomized trials based on ", n_boot, " bootstrap simulations"))
```

[image: Boxplot of coin flip simulations]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to visualize these results?

Comment: That `tmp` at the end of my answer is the same as your `boot_data` after the inner loop exits. The visualization would be the same as what you produce.  Regardless, I updated the answer to rename `tmp` to `boot_data` and provided a method to graph it. It took my laptop 4.5 seconds to run the simulation and produce the graph - so about 2 seconds faster than the original inner loop on my PC which would then need to run for 100 total times.