# R: Simulating the Population of a Fish Pond

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation, population-count

I am working with the R programming language.

I came across the following math puzzle recently:

- Suppose there is a pond with 100 fish
- Each day, there is a 5% chance that population of the pond increases by 5% of its current population
- A 5% chance that the population of the pond decreases by 5% of its current population
  a 90% chance that the population of the pond stays the same

I wrote some R code to represent the size of the pond over 1000 days:

```
set.seed(123)
n_days <- 1000
pond_population <- rep(0, n_days)
pond_population[1] <- 100


for (i in 2:n_days) {
    prob <- runif(1)
    if (prob <= 0.05) {
        pond_population[i] <- pond_population[i-1] + round(pond_population[i-1] * 0.05)
    } else if (prob > 0.05 && prob <= 0.10) {
        pond_population[i] <- pond_population[i-1] - round(pond_population[i-1] * 0.05)
    } else {
        pond_population[i] <- pond_population[i-1]
    }
}
 


plot(pond_population, type = "l", main = "Pond Population Over Time", xlab = "Day", ylab = "Population")
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am curious about the following modification to this problem - suppose each day you catch 10 distinct fish from this pond, tag these fish, and then put them back into the pond. Naturally, it is possible that some days you will catch fish that you previously caught in the past - and it is also possible that some of the fish you caught in the past will die. **After you have finished fishing on the 1000th day -  what percent of the current fish pond population will be known to you?**

I am interested in learning how to write a simulation procedure to answer this question - something that can be added to code I already wrote that keeps track of the size of fish pond population each day as well as the individual fish within the pond that you have already seen (e.g. imagine if each fish is assigned a unique ID).

I am not sure how to begin this problem - I think I might have to use "stacks" or "queues" for this problem, but I am not familiar with these concepts and how they would be used here.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

fish_pond_sim <- function(pop=100, days=1000, fished_per_day=10) {
    fish <- tibble(
            id = 1:pop,
            seen = FALSE,
            dead = FALSE
            )

    results <- tibble(
        population = pop,
        day = 1,
        seen = 0,
        dead = 0,
        seen_and_alive = 0
    )
    living <- pop
  for (i in 2:days) {
    prob <- runif(1)
    five_percent <- round(length(living) * 0.05)
    if (prob <= 0.05) {
      five_pct_sample <- sample(living, five_percent, replace = FALSE)
      fish[fish$id %in% five_pct_sample,]$dead <- TRUE
    } else if (prob > 0.05 && prob <= 0.10) {
      fish <- fish %>% add_row(
        id = max(fish$id):(max(fish$id) + five_percent), 
        seen = FALSE,
        dead = FALSE
      )
    }

    fished_sample <- sample(living, fished_per_day, replace = FALSE)
    fish[fish$id %in% fished_sample,]$seen <- TRUE
    living <- fish[!fish$dead,]$id
    results <- results %>% add_row(
      population = length(living),
      day = i,
      seen = sum(fish$seen),
      dead = sum(fish$dead),
      seen_and_alive = sum(fish$seen & !fish$dead)
    )
  }
    return(results)
}

result <- fish_pond_sim(1000, 1000) 

result %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = day)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = population, color = "Population")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = seen_and_alive, color = "Seen and Alive")) + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image: plot of fish]

To get the percentage which will be known to you, you can do something like this:

```
result %>%
    slice_tail() %>%
    pull(seen_and_alive_percentage) # 84.00424
```

Comment: @ Mark: Thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to modify this code to answer: After you have finished fishing on the 1000th day -  what percent of the current fish pond population will be known to you? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ Mark: Thank you so much for your update! I accepted your answer - if you have time, can you please update the ggplot graph as well? thank you so much!

Comment: update it with what? @stats_noob

Comment: As per your suggestion - "It would probably be more accurate to instead show the number of the alive fish we have seen". Is it possible to show this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh right! yeah sure

Comment: interesting thing about the population thing - if you decrease the population size, we see almost all fish (the lines overlap almost perfectly)

Comment: @ Mark: I have been thinking about this problem for some time now. I have been trying to think how to write mathematical formulas to estimate the probabilities and evaluate the limiting behaviors of the fish pond

Comment: If you are interested, you can check out these questions I asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735898/what-is-the-probability-of-knowing-someone-in-the-office

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731910/how-to-create-a-mathematical-model-of-an-elevator

Comment: very interesting! particularly the elevator problem. But my instinct is to model it programatically, as a stream of people arriving at the elevator every n seconds, rather than two separate markov chain models

Comment: thank you so much! I am very curious to see if someone will recommend any mathematical approaches to model these problems ... would sure make my time in the elevator go faster lol!

Comment: @ Mark: Unrelated question: do you have any ideas about how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76701351/html-xml-understanding-how-scroll-bars-work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254602/discussion-between-stats-noob-and-mark).

Comment: I tried to solve a related question a few days ago - can you please take a look at this question if you have time? I would be curious to know your thoughts! Thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76607184/r-writing-a-random-sampling-procedure-for-coin-flips

Comment: @stats_noob I posted my first question! Voronoi + graph related  I would be curious to know what you think! :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76896221/generate-teams-of-similar-strengths-with-contiguous-areas

Comment: great question! I have also wondered about these kinds of questions myself! I hope it gets answered soon!

Comment: btw you might find this interesting - here is a clustering algorithm that is meant for geospatial data to ensure that the clusters touch: https://www.dshkol.com/post/spatially-constrained-clustering-and-regionalization/

Comment: thank you for sharing that @stats_noob :-) you're welcome to try answering  I might put up a bounty when I'm able to

Comment: @stats_noob I had a read of the article you posted - it's interesting! I like the region-based clustering idea, but the issue is, they are calculating edge costs based on differences between nodes, which they only need to do once, whereas I'm still trying to figure out the cost function, and it would likely have to be recalculated after each step :'(

Comment: Hey Mark, I would like to place a bounty on your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76896221/generate-teams-of-similar-strengths-with-contiguous-areas) as a way to thank you for all the kind help you have provided me over the last few weeks - will that be ok?

Comment: @stats_noob that would be very sweet!  I was thinking of putting one on your question haha. I couldn't decide which one though. I was also thinking of putting one on mine too

Comment: @stats_noob I put a bounty on it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76896221/generate-teams-of-similar-strengths-with-contiguous-areas . Unsure if the bounty is large enough, but hopefully I get some good answers! :-)

Comment: you beat me to it :( I was feeling unwell these past few days and have not been vesting this website as frequently... do you have another question I can post one on?

Comment: oh I'm sorry to hear that @stats_noob! :-( hope you have been resting up and feel better soon

Comment: I'll have to think of something! I wish I had a fraction of the ideas you have- I generally have one idea and then can't stop thinking about it for a year or two 

Comment: haha i think we'd make a good team lol! btw are you a student? what industry are you in?

Comment: we were talking about this question earlier - I think someone was finally able to come up with an answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76981649/how-to-approximate-polygons-postal-code-zones-from-point-data

Comment: hi @stats_noob! I'm sorry for taking so long to reply to you. I'm going through a bit of a rough time :( I'm studying a bit, in economics, but study isn't going so well (i get easily distracted by other things, e.g. StackOverflow). Just quit a non-coding related job with the hope of getting a coding related one

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't clear what you meant by you want "alternate and new ways to solve this problem". Here's my attempt using vectorized functions in R's `dplyr::` and `purrr::` libraries for succinct code.

Final data shows 93% of fishes are known/marked in the end!

```r
library(tidyverse) ; 
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(patchwork) # for composing plots


# initialization
fishes <- rep(0, 1000) # 0 represents all the fish in the pond ; 1 are the marked fishes

prob_change <- .05 # probability of population increase = prob of population decrease
frac_change <- .05 # population fraction change with every day
fish_caught <- 10 # number of fish caught for marking

num_of_days <- 1000 # number of days for simulation to run


# Single simulation run
next_day <- function(fishpop, dummy)
{
  # difference in population size to increase or decrease
  pop_diff <- round(frac_change * length(fishpop)) # 5% of current population
  
  pop_red <- length(fishpop) - pop_diff
  
  # random variable 
  p = runif(1)
  
  # new population
  fishpop_list <- 
    case_when( # a vectorized if_else statement from dplyr:: package
      p <= prob_change ~ list(sample(fishpop, size = pop_red)), # subsample from current population (5% less)
      p >= (1 - prob_change) ~ list(c(fishpop, rep(0, pop_diff))), # add to current population
      .default = list(fishpop)
  )
  
  fishpop <- fishpop_list[[1]] # extract population from the list
  
  # fishing and marking with 1
  fishpop[sample(length(fishpop), size = fish_caught)] <- 1
  
  return(fishpop)
}


# run simulation over many days

# create iterator list : first element is the initial fish state ; others are dummies
iterator <- as.list(0:num_of_days)
iterator[[1]] <- fishes


# data frame to store daily stats and the simulations
daily_stats <- 
  tibble(day = 0:num_of_days,
         iterator = iterator) %>% 
  
  # run simulation for each day, store resulting fish state in "fishes" and use result for next iteration
  mutate(fishes = accumulate(iterator, next_day)) %>% 
  
  # summarize data
  mutate(total = map_int(fishes, length),
         marked_count = map_int(fishes, ~length(.x[.x == 1])),
         fraction_marked = marked_count / total)


# plotting
total_count <- 
  ggplot(daily_stats, aes(day, total)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) + geom_line(alpha = 0.2)

marked_count <- 
  ggplot(daily_stats, aes(day, marked_count)) + 
      geom_point(alpha = 0.2) + geom_line(alpha = 0.2)

# show plots : one below the other
total_count / marked_count
```

[image]

```r
# Show fraction of fish population marked
daily_stats %>% select(-2, -3) %>% tail
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>     day total marked_count fraction_marked
#>   <int> <int>        <int>           <dbl>
#> 1   995   438          422           0.963
#> 2   996   438          422           0.963
#> 3   997   438          423           0.966
#> 4   998   438          425           0.970
#> 5   999   460          428           0.930
#> 6  1000   460          428           0.930
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this is quite cool! I like the use of `accumulate`

Comment: Thank you! `accumulate` makes the code succinct but I do acknowledge that it is harder to follow the flow of code for new users

Comment: I mean, it's much easier to read than mine 